# NodeJS: Recall function after finished

Tags: node.js

I have a function that does some work. When it is finished it calls the callback. After that I get the 'END' in console. But i need to execute again the same function. How can I do that? Thx.

```
function start(callback){
  //... some work ... 
  if(work_finished){
    callback();
  }
}

start(function(){
    console.log('END');
});
```

Comment: You mean you want the function to call itself? That's called recursion, it's available in many (all?) languages and you can just go ahead and do it...

Comment: “But i need to execute again the same function”, help to explain in which function call which function again?

Comment: I think you need to explain a little bit more what you want to achieve, with real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function is asynchronous, you can create a wrapper function and literally just call it again from the callback.  Note, without any terminating conditions, this will run forever.

```
function start(callback){
  //... some work ... 
  if(work_finished){
    callback();
  }
}

function run() {
    start(function(){
        console.log('END');
        run();
    });
}
```

---

If your function is not asynchronous, the above operation will eventually cause a stack overflow (due to infinite recursion) so you'd have to have the caller of `start()` trigger it again:

```
function start(callback){
  //... some work ... 
  if(work_finished){
    callback();
  }
  // then return true or false depending upon whether you want
  // it to keep getting called again
  return true;
}

function run() {
    var more;
    do {
        more = start(function(){
            console.log('END');
        });
    } while (more === true);
}
```

---

And, if you just want your function called on some regular time interval, you can use `setInterval()` like this:

```
// call my function every 5 seconds
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    start(function(){
        console.log('END');
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thx! The first answer with asynchronous functions was what I was looking for :).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to repeatedly execute functions in node.

- Recursive calls

code:

```
function start(callback){
  //... some work ... 
  if(work_finished){
    callback();
    // call function again
    // should be OK if some work is async so it doesn't 
    // block the thread
    start(callback);
    // or schedule to be called at end of event loop
    // setImmediate(start, callback);
  }
}

start(function(){
    console.log('END');
});
```

- Execute function any number of additional times which would require number of calls to be tracked
- set the function up on an interval to be called ~n milliseconds

`setInterval(start, 1000, callback);`